# Need to fill in chair gaps

Tags: woodworking

I have painted two slatted wood chairs white, (slats run horizontally).
The slats are 1.5" wide and the gaps between are 1/2".
I tried painting black stripes to imitate piano keys along the side edges.
However with the gaps in between it has ended up looking more like a upc 
code.  I need to fill in the gaps where the black keys would be.  I have 
thought of using paint stir sticks, painting them black, to connect the gaps where the black keys would be.  My husband thinks it will be hard to glue them
on the painted surface of the chairs.  Is there another way to fill in the gaps 
on the chairs, or can you suggest a better way to adhere the "black keys", which
will be painted, to the painted chair.  These chairs are to be donated to a church auction, and I don't want them to fall apart quickly.  Thank you for any suggestions.   Penny

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A picture would be really helpful here.

Comment: A picture would be helpful. Where you want to glue sand the paint and use gorilla glue. Lightly moisten the wood with water prior to putting the glue on don't use two much as gorilla glue expands and fills gaps then sets really strong. I use this glue for repairing chairs and find it to be one of the best long lasting glues that I have used. If you put two much glue on and it comes out of the cracks I wipe it off before dried , or sand. Then paint it works quite well holds paint and is strong.

Comment: downvoted because the question is competely unclear without promised pics. (promised more than a year ago).  "Community"s bump algorithm needs a bit of work i'd say.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you are on the right train of thought - gluing in a filler panel. I would stay away from paint sticks, they are very thin and will not hold up to the forces working against a chair. You probably want to use material that is at least 1/4" thick.

As for securing them, wood glue (PVA) will stick best to freshly sanded and clean wood; scuffing up the paint will provide for better adhesion but still not as good as wood on wood.  Epoxy is an option as mentioned in another answer but is more difficult to work with and if not mixed properly or in the right proportions, will not work as-expected.

I think your best case scenario is sanding down the painted areas to accept glue, gluing in the new panel, and then re-painting the piece.

Comment: okay thanks   are the forces you are talking about people sitting in the chair and the slats moving some?  If I go to a 1/4" in wood could I use a small air nailer to nail in the slats?

Comment: Yes exactly, the chair is going to move a bit when people sit on it. Without seeing the design I couldn't say whether they could be nailed.

Comment: thanks again, I will take a pic and see if I can figure out how to get it on here.

Answer (score -1):

e-p-o-x-y.  just mix and fill.  once dry, sand and paint like wood.

Comment: Epoxy is not going to close a 1/2" x X" (however tall the slats are) gap on it's own without a form of some sort

Comment: yes -thats true, but only if you use a liquid epoxy.  epoxies are available in many viscosities, strengths and various physical and chemical properties.  just put some tape behind it or mix with an epoxy filler to make it more like a putty than a liquid, then just form it like playdough